# How to Change Default GWTBootstrap3 Theme

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, gwt

I'm trying to change the default GWTBoostrap3 theme without any luck. [I found this link](https://github.com/gwtbootstrap3/gwtbootstrap3/wiki/Custom-Theme). I have done what is explained but I don't see any change. Where must the 'resource' folder be located? I created this folder inside my WAR/nameofmyapp folder, put my theme.css file and modified my .gwt.xml file by adding these lines:

```
<public path='resource'>
    <include name='css/*.css'/>
</public>
<stylesheet src='css/theme.css'/>
```

[I downloaded these CSS theme files](https://bootswatch.com/3/) with still no changes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want to check out a working example look at here https://github.com/gwtbootstrap3/gwtbootstrap3-demo/tree/master/src/main/resources/org/gwtbootstrap3/demo/client . It shows that the css files are in the resource folder relative to the resource.gwt.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about [Public Path](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModules):

> Modules can specify which subpackages are *public*, causing the named
>   package and its subpackages to be added to the public path. The public
>   path is the place in your project where static resources referenced by
>   your GWT module, such as CSS or images, are stored. When you compile
>   your application into JavaScript, all the files that can be found on
>   your public path are copied to the module’s output directory. (...)
>   When referencing public resources from a Module XML File, just use the
>   relative path within the public folder, the module’s base URL will be
>   prepended automatically. (...)

You have specified your public package to be named `resource` and to include `css/*.css` files. So you should put the `theme.css` file to `full.path.to.the.package.resource.css` package.

In other words, the `path` attribute of the `public` tag is relative to the folder where the `<module>.gwt.xml` file is.

Comment: Thank you Adam, in fact I was putting the files in the wrong folder: they must be saved in myapp/public/css and the xml file must have this line <public path='public'>